# How use settings.local.php with Acquia Cloud

Tags: 8, version-control, acquia-dev-desktop, acquia-cloud

I try to setup my `.gitignore` file. My **local repo** is a clone from my Drupal 8 distro from Acquia Cloud.

(I want to theme my template locally and then, step by step I want to push it to `Dev` on Acquia Cloud.)

So regarding handeling `settings.php`, whether or not to ignore `settings.php` and whether or not use `settings.local.php`:

If I look in my current `settings.php` is see this:

```
// On Acquia Cloud, this include file configures Drupal to use the correct
// database in each site environment (Dev, Stage, or Prod). To use this
// settings.php for development on your local workstation, set $db_url
// (Drupal 5 or 6) or $databases (Drupal 7 or 8) as described in comments above.
```

I am confused and don't know anymore how to setup my `.gitignore` file with all this information and whether or not use `settings.local.php`. Please can somebody advice my what I have to do exactly, so it's setup correctly from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The default `.gitignore` file that ships with your Acquia Cloud git repository is fine as it is. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/193251/23961

I also advised against adding `settings.php` to your `.gitignore` file [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193226/gitignore-file-setup-for-acquia-cloud/193251#comment233392_193251).

Using `settings.local.php` is optional. Details about the file are available in the file or the [online Drupal documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites!example.settings.local.php/8) as described already [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193226/gitignore-file-setup-for-acquia-cloud/193251#comment233400_193251).

Comment: ok thanks but whats confusion me is that you say _'file that ships with your Acquia Cloud git repository is fine as it is.'_. But if i look in that file i see:
`# Ignore configuration files that may contain sensitive information.
sites/*/settings*.php
sites/*/services*.yml`. Do i have to get rid of `sites/*/settings*.php` ? And what is the difference between `sites/*/settings*.php` and `settings.php` (so without the asterisk) ?

Comment: `settings.php` is your main configuration file which I think should be kept under version control. `settings*.php` can represent `settings.local.php` which is for your local environment only. You may decide to ignore it from git completely.

Comment: so if i add only `settings*.php` to `.gitignore` it will only ignore e.g. `settings.local.php` and will not ignore `settings.php` ? And what still confusing me is if i read in the files and internet documentation they all say that i have to ignore `.gitignore` because of `# Ignore configuration files that may contain sensitive information.` But you suggest the opposite?

Comment: If you only use `settings.local.php` you don't have to use a wildcard character and can enter the complete filename directly if you wish to ignore it on your `.gitignore` file. The caveat `Ignore configuration files that may contain sensitive information` is made for files containing sensitive information such as credentials for connecting to the database. On Acquia Cloud you have a `require()` line that handles connecting to the database without exposing database credentials so you're safe.

Comment: But if I add `settings*.php` to .gitignore, will it not ignore `settings.php` then? (just to understand).

Comment: `settings*.php` will ignore `settings.php`, `settings.local.php` or `settings.testing.php`. * is a wildcard character, which means it replaces any character between the two strings `settings` and `.php`. If you want to ignore certain files only, it's easier to add the full filename, e.g. `settings.local.php`. Else, if you really want to ignore `settings*.php` but still want to keep `settings.php` under version control, then add a new line with `!settings.php`

Comment: thanks a lot. I will do it like you suggest. I post [another question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193533/git-making-code-changes-in-local-branch-develop-and-push-to-acquia-cloud-dev) regarding pushing code from Dev desktop and branches to Acquia Cloud. After this i am ready to start.