# Git making code changes in local branch 'develop' and push to Acquia Cloud Dev

Tags: version-control, acquia-dev-desktop

I cloned *Drupal 8 core and modules* from my Acquia Cloud distro into my local repo.

In my local repo I have 2 branches `* develop`and `master`. Currently I am in `develop` branch. I made some small changes to the `.gitignore` file and in `sites/default/settings/php`

(in the `develop` branch i want to make all my changes to code, themes and add contributed modules).

Currently i am in `develop` branch. When i try from *Dev desktop*: **Push code to Cloud Dev** I get this message:

> NOTE: Your locally deployed branch 'develop' doesn't match 'master'
>   deployed in the Cloud environment 'dev'. You will have to deploy
>   'develop' in the Cloud to see your code changes.

I know I get this message because I am currently in `develop` branch. But what do I have to do exactly before **Push code to Cloud Dev** to avoid this error message? What is the recommended procedure exactly to make changes to my code locally (on another branch) and **Push code to Cloud Dev**? And is it advisable to make those changes to code on another branch e.g. `develop`?

**Update:**

1. I select `develop` in Acquia Cloud dev environment after `git push
   origin develop`. Till when? When do i have to choose `master` again?
2. In my local repo i have added branch `develop` to add all my
   contributed modules and to develop the frontend etc. When do i have
   to merge it to `master` exactly? Or do i have to stay on `develop`
   all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply means you need your `develop` branch to be pushed to the remote Acquia Cloud repository.

`$ git push origin develop`

Once you do so, just select `develop` in your Acquia Cloud dev environment. You'll now by in synch between your local and remote branch and will be able to push code as you expect.

UPDATE:

1. Using the `develop` branch can be permanent or not, it's up to you.
   You can, say, have `develop` always checked out in dev, `master` in
   stage, and a git tag in prod. `develop` would then be your
   cutting-edge branch while `master` would be safer and primarily for
   QA. Sometimes, you'd have to delete `develop` and create it again
   from `master` to clean things up. It's part of a normal workflow.
2. Don't be mistaken between a [feature branch](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow) and a regular branch. `develop` isn't a feature branch, it's an integration branch. This means that you could have a feature branch locally called, say, `twig-fixes` that you would merge with `develop` when you're happy with the changes. You would then test your feature one last time in the `develop` branch locally and/or on Acquia Cloud, and then would take it from there.

NOTE: always create feature branches from `master` as it's your stable branch.

Example workflow:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
$ git checkout -b twig-fixes
```

Do your work and commit changes to the feature branch, and, when you're ready to test your changes on the Acquia dev environment, merge your branch into the `develop` branch and push it to origin:

```
$ git checkout develop
$ git pull origin develop
$ git merge twig-fixes
$ git push origin develop
```

If all looks good, merge the feature branch into `master` using the `squash` option, to compact all commits into one commit only.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --squash twig-fixes
$ git commit -m "Squashing twig-fixes"
$ git push origin master
```

If all looks good again in `master`, then you're free to delete your feature branch.

Comment: thanks a lot. I update my question to have things clear.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I placed a [new question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193890/git-local-repo-and-adding-drupal-8-contributed-modules) regarding adding contributed modules.

Comment: currently i am adding contributed modules etc on my integration branch `develop`. I pushed my code to _Acquia Cloud_ using `git push origin develop`. **1)** When my client commits his code to _Acquia Cloud Dev repo_. What do I have to do exactly, so I make sure i have all the new code, regarding to branching/merging? **2)** And also if my client wants to clone the _Acquia Cloud Dev repo_ how do I make sure he has all latest code. Which branch he has to clone, or do I have to merge before?

Comment: sorry, do you have an answer on above, last comment? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I answered #1 already above, by giving a `git merge` example. Whether you opt for a `git merge` or `git rebase` workflow is  up to you and your git strategy. There are plenty of git experts that can help you dive into advanced git strategies if you need to at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git - On #2, you simply have to use the 'Teams & Permissions' feature on the Acquia subscription to invite anybody to get access to the sub and repo. See https://docs.acquia.com/network/teams

Comment: ok thanks. I have 4 big websites where we want to use Acquia hosting, but also 3 smaller websites, where client wants to host on shared hosting. Here I [asked a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36112220/deploy-git-pull-latest-commits-from-acquia-cloud-staging-repo-to-live-site-on) about deploying from Acquia Cloud to shared host.