# Git local repo in combination with Acquia Cloud Dev repo adding contributed modules with Drush

Tags: 8, drush, version-control, acquia-dev-desktop, acquia-cloud

I try to add contributed modules to my local repo following [this article](https://docs.acquia.com/cloud/manage/code/install-module#local).

```
curl https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/admin_toolbar-8.x-1.14.tar.gz | tar fz
```

Its not placing the `.tar.gz` file in my local repo?

What I'm doing wrong? After (when it's placed) I want to extract the folder and commit the module. Is this best practice adding contributed modules to my local repo or do i have to use Drush, and if so how do I have to use it in combination with my Git/Drupal workflow?

**Update:**

1. I used Drush `drush dl admin_toolbar` to add the module.
2. I committed the module and pushed it to my Acquia Cloud Dev
   environment
3. Now from Acquia Dev Desktop `SSH to this server` I want to use
   `drush en admin_toolbar`. But then I get this message:

*Command pm-enable needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will   [error]
need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run
this command.
The drush command 'en admin_toolbar' could not be executed.          [error]*

- Can't I use Drush to enable modules on Acquia Cloud Dev environment?
- Is this the preferred, most fast/handiest workflow, or is there a
  better workflow to use (when you use a locally cloned repo in combination with Acquia Cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right command is:

```
curl https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/admin_toolbar-8.x-1.14.tar.gz | tar xz
```

`f` process  a file, but you want to process the standard input (provided by curl). So remove the f and add the `x` option to uncompress file.

Anyway I think is better to use Drush. Drush can handle dependencies (it can download dependant modules when you enable a module) and is easier to use:

```
drush dl admin_toolbar
```